# hector quadrotor controller

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking to eventually modify the controller used for the hector quadrotor.

I'm a bit confused, when I look on github (https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/tree/indigo-devel/hector_quadrotor_controller) the hector_quadrotor_controller directory has a src folder with multiple .cpp files inside, but when I search my install for the hector_quadrotor_controller folder, neither of the two results have it.

I don't understand why it's not present? (I have followed the install instructions for the hector tutorials).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210804/hector-quadrotor-controller/) by [c123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22663/c123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on 2015-06-09**:
Install it as source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

credit goes to eng/Esraa Magdy
what I will write is for installing hector on ros kinetic

as a piece of advice : remove your installation by deleting it from your catkin_ws/src and then delete the whole file of build and devel inside catkin workspace
here we begin

cd ~/catkin_ws/src
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-unique-identifier
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-geographic-info
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-laser-geometry
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf-conversions
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joy
mkdir hector_pkg

git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor
git clone -b catkin https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models
git clone -b catkin https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam

in the file hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/urdf/CMakeLists.txt
find the following line: 's/option(USE_PROPULSION_PLUGIN "Use a model of the quadrotor propulsion system" ON)
change ON to OFF

in hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/urdf/CMakeLists.txt
find s/option(USE_AERODYNAMICS_PLUGIN "Use a model of the quadrotor aerodynamics" ON)
change ON to OFF

cd ..
catkin make
source devel/setup.bash

to test if everything is okay
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch

in a new terminal enable the motors using the following :
rosservice call /enable_motors "enable: true"

---

Originally posted by [Alaa Hesham](https://answers.ros.org/users/33520/alaa-hesham/) with karma: 91 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan_Dirgantara](https://answers.ros.org/users/34985/ryan_dirgantara/) on 2018-05-06**:
Hello there, may i know what is the purpose of changing the the quadrotor propulsion and aerodynamics from ON to OFF?

Thank you